# Adding more filters to MAXIFS under Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following set of data from Google Sheets (I am using 2 Google Sheets):

```
SHEET #1: KDCAlerts

ROWID       ACCT PRIO  TID     ACTION         TICK          CPRICE  CREATEDATE                                          
1440026     20   1     X3T8K5  X_OPEN_LEVEL   BITMEX:BTCUSD 12000   10/5/2022 13:56:46                                                                  
1993961     20   1     X3T8K5  X_TP_1_LEVEL   BITMEX:BTCUSD 12000   10/5/2022 18:17:12                                                                  
2537954     20   1     X3T8K5  X_TARGET_LEVEL BITMEX:BTCUSD 12000   10/5/2022 18:17:46
```

Below is the second sheet:

```
SHEET #2: KDCLog:

STATUS      ALERT   ID
IN PROCESS          X3T8K5
IN PROCESS          YNILX5
```

What I am trying to do is to get the latest *ACTION* in the set. In this case, it would be *X_TARGET_LEVEL* since it has a CREATEDATE of *10/5/2022 18:17:46*

I had used the following as a start:

```
= FILTER(KDCAlerts!E2:E10, KDCAlerts!H2:H10=( MAXIFS(KDCAlerts!H2:H10,KDCAlerts!D2:D10, C7)) )
```

It DOES work - but - it depends upon **DATE** **only** to find the correct answer. This is not ideal. I need to add in another filter **TID (represented as C7)** as well.

How can this be done

TIA

**UPDATE:**
@player0 , @Terio

Thanks for the responses! I added more information to the original post (for further clarity).

I created the following which does what I basically need (assigning a status to the **KDCLog!Status** field )

```
=IF( ISBLANK(C7) , "NEW", ( IF ( LEN(R7) < 2 , "STAGING"  , ( IF (  NOT ( ISBLANK(  FILTER(KDCAlerts!J, KDCAlerts!H=( MAXIFS(KDCAlerts!H,KDCAlerts!D, C7)) ) ) )  , "IN PROCESS" , ( IF(  NOT( ISBLANK(  FILTER(KDCAlerts!L, KDCAlerts!H=( MAXIFS(KDCAlerts!H,KDCAlerts!D, C7)) ) )  )  ,  "COMPLETE" ,  (  FILTER(KDCAlerts!E, KDCAlerts!H=( MAXIFS(KDCAlerts!H,KDCAlerts!D, C7)) ) )  ) )  )  )   ) )   )
```

but - still having the issue with the use of date (as mentioned above).

Will try the suggestions you made and update the post with my results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution like this?

```
=INDEX(SORTN(FILTER({E2:E,H2:H},D2:D="X3T8K5"),1,,2,FALSE),,1)
```

Change *TID* filters with ***C7***

Comment: From sheet KDCLog I tried:

=INDEX(SORTN(FILTER({KDCAlerts!E2:E\H2:H};KDCAlerts!D2:D="X3T8K5");1;;2;FALSE);;1)

and

=INDEX(SORTN(FILTER({KDCAlerts!E2:E\KDCAlerts!H2:H};KDCAlerts!D2:D="X3T8K5");1;;2;FALSE);;1)

In both cases, I got a parsing error

Comment: Sorry, probably the declaration of array, I've modified the formula

Comment: Thanks! that seems to have done the trick! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=XLOOKUP(D2; D2:D4; A2:H4;;;-1)
```

[image]

Comment: From KDCLog, I tried the following from the Status field

=XLOOKUP(KDCAlerts!D2; KDCAlerts!D2:D4; KDCAlerts!A2:H4;;;-1)

Message: Array result was not expanded because it would override data in C7

Should I be doing something differently

Comment: @CaseyHarrils can you share a copy of your sheet? the meaning of the error you got is as follows: you are trying to return range A:H - that's 8 columns so you will need to have empty space for that so the formula could roll out. but there is something placed in C7 so it can't roll out properly resulting in the error.